# BJT Constant current LED driver

Tags: microcontroller, led, bjt, constant-current, power-dissipation

I need to build a constant current driver for a LED with a forward voltage of 3.4V and 350mA maximum current. The driver will be controlled by a PWM signal from a 3.3V MCU.

Reading [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15325/controlling-high-output-leds-with-a-microcontroller) and doing the calculations using my system specs, I came up with the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuAAf4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I had to choose a 12V power supply due to the high forward voltage of the LED, which resulted in a minimum power supply voltage of 6.5V. Therefore I couldn't use a 5V power supply.

However, I'm concerned about the power dissipation on the transistor. If my calculations are right, the power dissipated across it would be (neglecting base current and considering Vbe=0.7V):

[image]

And the [BCP56](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BCP56_BCX56_BC56PA.pdf) can only dissipate a maximum of 1.35W with properly sized mounting pad in the PCB.

First of all I would like to know if the my calculations are right and, in case they are, what would be a good solution.

The only two options I can think of are either picking a beefier transistor that can dissipate more power or reducing the power supply voltage, although I like the idea of using as 12V power supply since it's easier to find locally.

Furthermore, is BJT a good solution for this type of driver or changing for a MOSFET based driver a more suitable option?

Comment: I would recommend you use a Darlington power transistor, like the TIP series. Mosfets are recommended only for High power LEDs like 5-10W and above.

Comment: It sounds like you want the transistor either fully on or fully off, so I would use a FET. I find them simpler to understand and they have lower power loss at high current. For the circuit you have, I believe you want R1 on the collector, not the emitter, otherwise the current through the resistor will raise the emitter voltage, and change your base-emitter voltage. Most of the power will be dissipated by R1, not the transistor, that might be more obvious when you move R1. EDIT: I may have misunderstood your intention, are you trying to use the BJT to control current instead of a resistor?

Comment: Also, I highly recommend simulating all transistor circuits. LTSpice has good features and is free.

Comment: @pscheidler Yes, I'm trying to use the BJT to control the current and therefore R1 needs to be on the emitter side. I simulated it in LTSpice, and it seems that my power dissipation calculation is right. Just wanted to check if anyone can recommend a better circuit than mine. Thanks!

Comment: Do you prefer using MOSFETs? If so, Trevor's circuit is a very standard approach combining a small signal BJT with an NMOS. Another approach that is almost identical replaces the NMOS with another BJT. They both work just fine. So it really is a matter of what you can get and want to pay for, I think. There are other approaches, too, of course. In fact, I can think of at least 5 or 6 different basic approaches where all of them are about the same cost but have various advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Can you use a much lower supply voltage? Because this is incredibly inefficient. You're using 4.2 Watts of power (12V * .35A), and only 1.2 Watts is going to the LED. The remaining 3 Watts is turned to heat. *Your circuit works better as heater than an LED driver :)*

Comment: @VincePatron yes I'm aware it's extremely inefficient and it would be much better using a power supply of 7V. However, where I live it's hard to find power supplies with voltages other than the most 'common' ones (5V, 12V, 24V).

Comment: Consider using an LED driver IC, such as the [MIC4801](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic4801.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be using 5V and a MOSFET here to limit the current required from the GPIO and coupling it in a typical current limiter as shown below.

R1 and Vbe or Q1 roughly set the current limit. If you need it more accurate than that you either need a pot in there or a more active circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fETzkX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The gate threshold of the MOSFET needs to be under or close to 1V. Power lost to the MOSFET is about 300mW and R1 is 215mW.

Comment: I've seen this circuit in other threads but I was reluctant of using it due to its higher component count since I intend to replicate the circuit to control several LEDs individually. However, after a second look I realised this approach is much more efficient than the one I posted and I would be able to use components with smaller footprints due to lower power dissipation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your design wastes too much voltage on R1. Here is a design that only drops 0.6V across R1, allowing you to use a 5V supply, which means less power wasted in the transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW69i8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However this design is too dependent on the characteristics of the transistor. Better to use a more sophisticated circuit.

If your goal is to minimize power wasted, better to use a switching current regulator. You will find many sold as LED drivers.

Comment: Pretty sure that wont supply enough base current to run 350mA through Q1.

Comment: @Trevor_G The BCP56 datasheet gives a minimum beta of 40.

Comment: True, still a pretty heavy load on a GPIO though.

Comment: That is true. I figure OP hasn't thought about that either.